# Linear spans are equal if they contain one another's generators

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space, and suppose $M = [\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_k\} ]$ and $L = [ \{b_1, b_2, \ldots, b_m\} ]$ are subspaces of $V$.

Prove that $M = L$ iff $a_i$ is an element of $L$, for every $i = 1, 2, \ldots, k$, and $b_j$ is an element of $M$, for every $j = 1, 2, \ldots, m$.

Comment: Have you ever worked on this problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I don't even know when two linear shells are equal.

Comment: Please, call it _linear span_ . There, of course, exists theory of linear shells, but it's not linear algebra.

Comment: Oh, sorry. English isn't my first language so I didn't know what it is properly called.  
I have this task in my book in linear algebra but there isn't a solution nor any tips so I have no clue how to solve it.

Comment: You should start by writing out (and understanding!) what it means to say that $M$ is the linear span of the $a_i$, in other words, what can you say about each vector in $M$ in terms of the $a_i$? Do the same for $L$. Now if each $b_i$ is in $M$, can you conclude that every vector in $L$ is in $M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Casteels already mentioned, here are some hints:

The implication $M = L$ follows every basis vector is included in the other side is more or less trivial. (Why?)

A vector $v$ is in $L$, if it can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors of $L$, ie.
$$v = \sum_{i=1}^m b_i$$
So start with $v = a_i$ and look what happens!

I hope that helped you already, nobody will post a complete solution on that if you haven't tried anything ;-)